# Issue with order by for datetime column in datatables

Tags: datetime, datatables

I have a column having datetime objects in my table. I am using datatables plugin.
Upon trying to sort the particular column, it gets sorted with errors. Like,for the following dates

```
Aug. 20, 2018, 11:16 a.m.  
Aug. 2, 2018, 12:25 p.m. 
Aug. 4, 2018, 3:03 p.m.
```

I get the sorted result as

```
Aug. 2, 2018, 12:25 p.m.  
Aug. 20, 2018, 11:16 a.m.  
Aug. 4, 2018, 3:03 p.m.
```

What should be done to correct this?

Comment: Hi @p.ry, because it is considered as string instead of timestamp.

Comment: if you see [this](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) it will be done by jquery internally, or add more detail, what you have tried.

Comment: @yash, so the data-order attribute on the td should do it,right?  Like, `<td data-order="{{u.created_time|date:"U"}}">{{u.created_time}}</td>`. Doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: if you have your data in `{{u.created_time}}` in milisecods, then it will sort data properly even if it it string, so if your return data is miliseconds like `1354406400`, instead of `Aug. 2, 2018, 12:25 p.m.`, then it will be able to sort, you can use `<td data-order="{{u.created_time}} ">{{u.created_time|date:"U"}}"</td>`

Comment: @yash tried formatting it,`<td data-order="{{u.created_time|date:"U"}}">{{u.created_time|date:"DATETIME_FORMAT"}}</td>`.Still no luck.

Comment: what is the value of `"u.created_time"`

Comment: a datetime value like `Aug. 4, 2018, 3:03 p.m.  `

Comment: that's issue. when you sort by date, it will call ajax to get data, at that time it will sort data on date column which is actually string, so it will sort data based on  blank, 1 to 10 , A to Z format.starting from first character. If you change `Aug. 4, 2018, 3:03 p.m` this by your milliseconds then it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in  [jquery official document](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/#DataTables_Table_0_wrapper) , you can only sort data for which format is mentioned.

and to sort date or time, you can add following lines to sort the date or time :

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
     columnDefs: [
       { type: 'date-uk', targets: 0 }
     ]
  } );
```

0 is the index of column. you can modify that based on your column index. 
And you can change type `date-uk` to any other which is mentioned in document, if you receive data in same format.